# Django submit form in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

i know that there are a lot of posts with similar topic as this one, but none of them seem to be a useful fix in my case at least. As the headline describes i want to be able to send a new comment form to my database from a bootstrap modal. My data is being shown just fine so the only problem i got is that when i fill out the data for a new comment and press the submit button the modal is just being dismissed and no action has happened in my DB. My best guess for why it is not working is because i got my modal data in a separated html file detail.html. But otherwise i was not able to display the right data for each posts.

button to open the modal in home.html:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary post_details-btn" class="open-modal" data-url="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}" width="17" height="17"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>
```

my modal in home.html where i display the data from detail.html in the div with the id = modal-div

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">WINNER:</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"                       aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modal-div"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
        </div>
```

my jquery to display the html code from detail.html in the modal, this code is also located in home.html

```
                 var modalDiv = $("#modal-div");
                $(".post_details-btn").on("click", function() {
                  $.ajax({
                     
                    url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
                    success: function(data) {
                      $('#myModal2').modal('show');
                      modalDiv.html(data);
                    }
                  });
                });
```

detail.html

```
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
 
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 ">
      <div class="card-body">
        <!-- comments -->
        <h2>{{ comments.count }} comments</h2>

        {% for comment in comments %}
        <div class="comments" style="padding: 10px;">
          <p class="font-weight-bold">
            {{ comment.name }}
            <span class=" text-muted font-weight-normal">
              {{ comment.created_on }}
            </span>
          </p>
          {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 ">
      <div class="card-body">
        {% if new_comment %}
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
          Your comment is awaiting moderation
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
        <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
          {{ comment_form.as_p }}
          {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>





{% endblock content %}
```

my post_detail function in views.py

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    allposts= Posts.objects.all()
    alltags = Tag.objects.all()

    post = get_object_or_404(Posts, pk=pk)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
            print("form is send!")

    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    
    context = {
        'alltags': alltags,
        'allposts': allposts,
        'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'new_comment': new_comment,
        'comment_form': comment_form,
        'alltags': alltags,
    }
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did manage to get a solution myself after days of researching. The solution was to add the url in action attribute in the detail.html to the function in views.py that handles the comment form.

```
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">
          {{ comment_form.as_p }}
          {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
        </form>
```